# Unable to display Image in Java Plugin Project

Tags: java, image, eclipse-plugin, swt

Image is not displayed in the application. Please find the project structure and code in the image file. Can you please help me to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Putting the `images` directory in the `src` directory is not recommended for plugins. Put the directory in the top level `BulkDemo` directory (like the existing `icons` directory).

Be sure to edit the `build.properties` and add the images directory so that it is included in the plugin build.

You can't use a file path for the `Image` constructor because your plugin will be packed in to a jar and resources in a jar are not files. Instead use `FileLocator`:

```
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());

URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("images/active.png"), null);

ImageDescriptor imageDesc = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(url);

label.setImage(imageDesc.createImage());
```

Comment: I have moved my images folder under BulkDemo. I have 'n' number of images in my project. May i know how to use just the relative path ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. You have to specify each image path individually.

Comment: My bad. I have around 400 images. Is that the only solution ?